# как в си называется тип данных бесзнаковый инт 8 бит?

Tags: c

Не могу найти как в си называется тип, обозначающий беззнаковый инт длиной 8 бит.

Comment: `unsigned char`?

Comment: `uint8_t`? (ещё 5 символов)

Comment: а вот незадача, unsigned char не обязательно 8 бит. да, сложно сейчас найти платформы где это не так, но я бы не был так категоричен

Comment: @EOF, int8_t работает, uint_8t - нет.

Comment: @DenverToha, подключите  заголовок `inttypes.h`.

Comment: Подключите `stdint.h`

Comment: @KoVadim Категоричен - если бы написал не вопросительный знак, а восклицательный :)